# Flutter Firebase get recordID

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the code below, I am trying to get the id of snap. This info is supposed to be recorded, later if the user tap on save.

But, I am not able to get the right id associated with the project selected. If you can put me to the right direction, it would be appreciated. Many thanks.

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users')
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                      .collection('projects')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      const Text("Loading.....");
                    else {
                      List<DropdownMenuItem <Project>> goalItems = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                         snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];

                       // print (gael.id);
                       // print(snap['project_Name']);
                        goalItems.add(
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: Project(snap['project_Name'], snap.id),//(snap['project_Name'], snap.id),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.89,
                              child: Text(
                                (snap['project_Name']),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            // ),

                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return Row(
                          children:<Widget> [
                            DropdownButton <Project>(
                              items: goalItems,
                              onChanged: (Project pro) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedProject = pro.name;

                                  taskNewValue ['project_Name'] = pro.name ;
                                  taskNewValue['project_ID'] = pro.id;
                                  print(pro.id);
                                });
                              },
                              value: selectedProject,
                              isExpanded: false,
                              hint:  Text(projectName,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color (0xff29B6F6)), //Color(0xff0d53dc)),
                              ),
                            )]);
                    }
                    return Container(
                      height: 0,width: 0,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
```

```
class Project {
 // var User(this.name, this.id);
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Project(this.id,this.name);
}
```

//Last modification done. When I remove value, it works, but, when I select a new item, it is not displayed

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users')
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                      .collection('projects')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      const Text("Loading.....");
                    else {
                      List<DropdownMenuItem <Project>> goalItems = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                        snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                        print(snap.id);
                        print(snap['project_Name']);

                        goalItems.add(
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: Project(snap.id, snap['project_Name']),
                            //(snap['project_Name'], snap.id),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width * 0.89,
                              child: Text(
                                (snap['project_Name']),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            // ),

                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            DropdownButton <Project>(
                              items: goalItems,
                              onChanged: (Project pro) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedProject = pro.name;
                                  project_ID=pro.id;
                                  myTest = pro.name;
                                  final test4 = Project(project_ID,  myTest);
                                //  print('ID');
                                //  print(pro.id);
                                //  print('name');
                                //  print(pro.name);
                                //  print('test4');
                                //  print(test4.id);
                                //  print(test4.name);
                                 // print(project_ID);
                                });
                              },
                             // value: Project(project_ID,myTest),//selectedProject,
                              isExpanded: false,
                              hint: Text(projectName,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color(
                                    0xff29B6F6)), //Color(0xff0d53dc)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ]);
                    }
                    return Container(
                      height: 0, width: 0,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
```

I have created a new page with the following code. I am getting the following error.

The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#50df7):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Project?'

I am not sure how to fix that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

var selectedProject;
var idProject;

DocumentSnapshot snap;

class MyTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTest({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTestState createState() => _MyTestState();
}

class _MyTestState extends State<MyTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('test'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {

            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body:

      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Users')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                .collection('projects')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                const Text("Loading.....");
              else {
                List<DropdownMenuItem <Project>> goalItems = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                  snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                  print(snap.id);
                  print(snap['project_Name']);

                  goalItems.add(
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: Project(snap.id, snap['project_Name']),
                      //(snap['project_Name'], snap.id),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .width * 0.89,
                        child: Text(
                          (snap['project_Name']),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                      // ),

                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      DropdownButton <Project>(
                        items: goalItems,
                        onChanged: (Project pro) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedProject = pro.name;
                            idProject = pro.id;
                           final test4 = Project(idProject,  selectedProject);
                            
                          });
                        },
                         value: selectedProject,
                        isExpanded: false,
                        hint: Text('test',//projectName,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Color(
                              0xff29B6F6)), //Color(0xff0d53dc)),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]);
              }
              return Container(
                height: 0, width: 0,
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Project {
  // var User(this.name, this.id);
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Project(this.id,this.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean when you say you're "not able to get the right id associated with the project selected."

Comment: right now, when I print the id, I always get the id of the last project.
But I need to get the id of the record selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom model like `Project`:

```
class Project {
  const Project(this.name, this.id);    
  final String name;
  final String id;
}
```

And instead of adding just the String names to the `DropdownButton` items add those models:

```
 List<DropdownMenuItem> goalItems = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                        DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                         test = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                      
                        goalItems.add(
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: Project(snap['project_Name'], snap.id),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.89,
                              child: Text(
                                (snap['project_Name']),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ),

                            //  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            // ),
                            value: (snap['project_Name']),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
```

Then you can get the `id` from the `Project` on the `onClick` listener:

```
return Row(
                          children:<Widget> [
                            DropdownButton(
                              items: goalItems,
                              onChanged: (Project pro) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedProject = pro;
                                  taskNewValue ['project_Name'] = pro.name ;
                                  taskNewValue['project_ID'] = pro.id;

//here I am trying to get the id of the record, so I can record the id when the user select save
                                });
                              },
                              value: selectedProject,
                              isExpanded: false,
                              hint:  Text(projectName,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color (0xff29B6F6)), //Color(0xff0d53dc)),
                              ),
                            )]);
                    }
```

Comment: Many thanks. I will try and come back to you.

Comment: I have tried but I am getting an error message. I am not sure why. Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.
Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:
  Parameter 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T)'
                        but argument is 'Null Function(Project)'.
The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'items' declared as     'List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>'
                    but argument is 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>'.
  Parameter 'value' declared as     'T'
                    but argument is 'dynamic'.

Comment: Could you pls try to change this `List<DropdownMenuItem>` to 
 List<DropdownMenuItem`<Porject>>`

Comment: I have tried, but now the error has changed. The error message is The operator '>>' isn't defined for the type 'Type'. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have find the origin of the error. But now I am getting a new error. type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Project>>?'
I have not defined List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>. I do not know why I am getting this error. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I have done some modifications and fixed the previous issue. But now I am getting the following error.type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Project?'

Comment: Does it come from here `selectedProject = pro.name;` . That should be `selectedProject = pro;`

Comment: I have modified selectedProject = pro.
Now, I am getting this error.
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Project'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value. It seems that two value are equal, but in the firebase each record are different

Comment: Can you print out `goalItems` so we see whats inside.

Comment: I have two elements. Project Name= test1, Project Name= test2 and two keys, one per record. When I ask to the application to print goalItems, I am getting
[DropdownMenuItem<Project>, DropdownMenuItem<Project>]

Comment: Try to change `value: selectedProject,` to `value: selectedProject.value?selectedProject:null`

Comment: After modification, I am getting this message
The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value

Comment: Can you print `snap.id` is it a valid `uid`. I have tried the code in a sandbox and it worked fine.

Comment: Hello Tarik, When I print snap.id I am getting the right uid. The uid are automatically generated by Firebase. I will try your code on another view and see if I am getting an error.

Comment: I have done some research. It seems that the problem is coming from Value.  I have done some modifications. If I remove Value, it works except that the screen does not display the new value of the item selected. I have updated my question.

Comment: Is you question code up to date? It again shows the value to a String and not to a Project.

Comment: I have tried to update my question, but the platform says that the queue is full. I will try again to update it later today

Comment: I was not updating it properly. It is up to date now. Many thanks for your help. It is appreciated.

Comment: This ` selectedProject = pro.name;` should be this ` selectedProject = pro;`

Comment: I have modified my code. I do not have the error anymore,  but, when I select an other item, it is not displayed. The dropdown widget keep displaying the hint: Text('Project')

Comment: Did you change the part in my last comment?

Comment: Yes. I have create a new view with the code. It is working now. Many thanks for your help.